# Get IIS file under inetpub folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I wanna get files from "C:\inetpub\media\archives\MySiteName\Test.isml\Segment0001\Test.ismv" file from MVC?

Doues IIS give permission to access own folders?

Comment: just because a folder is in \inetpub doesn't mean it's an "iis folder". you need to check the permissions on the folder to see if the IIS user account is allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a web-site or virtual directory pointing to somewhere in that path, you also need to add a mime-type for `.ismv`.

If you still have problems with accessing that file, update your answer and add the sub http status for the 404 as found in the log files.